# Printing Frequency and Duplicate Strings

Tags: c++

I apologize if I am asking something that someone has already asked. I am a total beginner, and I've been trying to find legible sources that I understand, to no avail.

I am trying to design a program that accepts commands through echo, and when user enters some strings, and -d, the program prints only the duplicate words, and when they write -c, it prints the frequency of the strings, in c++.

I have the code for the frequency part, and when I manually execute it file, it works for the frequency, but I don't understand the code.

```
int main() {
map<string, int> F;  //Stores frequency table
string s;                  //holds input;

while (cin>> s) F[s]++;

for (map<string, int>::iterator i=F.begin(); i != F.end(); i++){
  cout<< (*i).first << ":\t" << (*i).second<< "\n";
}

return 0;

}
```

The above code uses map, but it's a bit confusing.
I understand that .first prints the key, and .second gives the value. But, I don't understand the purpose of the while loop. It takes the string, say F[1]= abc, then it adds one to it? That doesn't make sense.

As for the for loop: What is the purpose of the iterator? Iterators are like pointers, but why are they used here? What's the point of printing out *i?

Comment: *That doesn't make sense.* -- What does `operator []` do in a `std::map`?  [Here is the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)

Comment: Please read the very first line of the documentation that I linked to.  *Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key* -- So a reference to the value is returned, and then 1 is added to it.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop first reads with cin into s until it false, when it will return false, ending the while loop. If s in already in F, it adds 1 to it to record how many times it appears. Then s changes and repeats the process. Printing out *i prints out how many times each string appears. This program does not seam to accept -c or -d for control.

Comment: Thinking it over, doesn't F[s]++  add input s into the map F, with ++ serving the purpose of not having multiple inputs being entered into the same place in the map? I think I am still confused about how F[s]++ results in recording how many times it appears?

Comment: @user9583887 `F[s]` returns a reference to the value for the the key `s` in the map `F`, creating the pair if it doesn't exist yet (in which case the default value is 0). The `++` operator then increments the reference's value. For the first occurrence of `s`, this is 0 -> 1. For the second occurrence of the same string, this will be 1 -> 2, and so on.